# How to create view to filter out certain results and group it in Oracle Reports? 

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, oraclereports

I'm actually working on Oracle reports. One of the situation I have is to create a parameter for the reports which is type of fees. I have a table called type_of_fees and one of the column is called `type_of_fees`

I have several records such as:

- monthly rental 1
- monthly rental 2
- monthly rental 3
- 1 month deposit
- 2 months deposit
- Aircond charges
- Utility
- 1 month advance
  -weekly rental

For the parameter, I would like to have a list of values to choose from which I intend from the dropdown:

1. Monthly Rental
2. Deposits
3. Airconditioning
4. Utilities
5. Others

So I would like when user select monthly rental it will show types of monthly rental I got in the table _onthly rental 1,monthly rental 2, monthly rental 3.

I would also like if other records such as the 1 month advance and weekly rental to be put under Others when selected. Now,if I'm not mistaken, I'm going to have to create a view to make things easier

I would imagine needing columns like SELECTION_TYPE and TYPE_OF_FEES.

how would i insert custom records such for the SELECTION TYPE which will show the appropriate type of fees?

example of view intended:

```
----------------------------------
selection_type | type_of_fees    |
----------------------------------
Monthly Rental  | monthly rental 1
----------------------------------
Monthly Rental  | monthly rental 2
----------------------------------
Monthly Rental  | monthly rental 3
----------------------------------
Deposits        | 1 month deposit
----------------------------------
Deposits        | 2 months deposit
----------------------------------
Airconditioning | Aircond charges
----------------------------------
Utilities       | Utility
----------------------------------
Others          | 1 month advance
----------------------------------
Others          | weekly rental
----------------------------------
```

How do I create this? especially the part to create data for the `selection_type` column. I'm not very familiar in creating views.

I have no problem querying out the data I intend to use but I just need to create the view so that I can use the selection_type to query out things easier:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TYPE_OF_FEES FROM TYPE_OF_FEES
WHERE TYPE_OF_FEES LIKE '%deposit%'
```

By the way I'm on Oracle. Please if anyone could explain and help.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are referring to Oracle Reportwriter / Reportbuilder the product bundled with Oracle Forms?

Oracle Reports you have to start with the basics.
Create the report to select all data regardless of selection_type.
This will allow you to concentrate on the structure of the query and the structuring of the report. It's quite crucial to get the structure of your report correct and use this as a basis for the report wizard to generate the report for you. You then customize the generated report accordingly.

Once you have the structure pinned down - create your parameter form and add your parameter(s) into query.

You are probably looking to create two LOV parameter fields with the first being selection_type and the second being type_of_fees. The latter being dependent on the value entered in the first.

[Oracle Reports Parameter Form documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/bi.1111/b32122/orbr_howto011.htm#i1069054)

Comment: thnx for your answer but in my case,i have done the report. all i want is to create the parameter of selection_type so that i can select one selection and report will filter and display it out. nvermind. i got the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question since i have found a way, to create a view with that particular `selection_type` for each `type_of_fees` i can use CASE WHEN.

using that i can construct the view as i want with new columns.